# How to use a Swift view controller in a React app?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I have an AR module written in Swift that I want to use within a React App. The display and interaction of my views is controlled by a view controller. Now I know I can export a single view and make use of the several online tutorials. But I am not sure how to do the same with a hierarchy of views controlled by a ViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it by wrapping the ViewController within a View that is then made available to React using the bridging headers.